# Setting a foreign key bigInteger to bigIncrements in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

So I'm trying to set a foreign key in my migrate file for laravel so the user table is simple but I'm trying to use bigIncrements instead of stand increments as such.

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->bigIncrements('id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('user_id')->unique();
        $table->string('avatar');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestampsTz();
    });
}
```

And when I do the other table I try to add foreign key to it I get a error saying the the foreign key is incorrectly formed. I'm confused as to how because I'm matching the column types. Here is the other table.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('social_logins', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->string('provider', 32);
        $table->string('provider_id');
        $table->string('token')->nullable();
        $table->string('avatar')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: Try getting rid of the `->unsigned()->index()` at the end of the foreign key statement

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Remove `unsigned()` from:

```
$table->bigIncrements('id')->unsigned();
```

And the other migration should look like this:

```
$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
....
$table->index('user_id');
```

Comment: Thank you so much that did it.

Comment: Or simply use `unsignedBigInteger`

Answer (score 7):

Reason is **primary** and **foreign** references must be of same type.

`bigIncrements()` wants `unsignedBigInteger()`

and `increments()` wants `unsignedInteger()`

If you are using

`$table->bigIncrements('id');` as a primary key in a users table:

then use

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id'); as foreign key
```

And if you are using `$table->increments('id');` as a primary key in a users table then use

```
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id'); as freign key.



$table->increments(); creates just integer and $table->bigIncrements(); creates big integer.
```

so the reference type must be the same.

Read more https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#adding-columns

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `bigIncrements` returns an unsignedBigInteger. 
In order to work the Foreign key must be an unsigned big integer with `index()`.